# failing to open alert box before redirection.ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to show an alert box before redirecting,but it's not working.The alert box only works if the 
redirection is not done.

i modified the popular Alert.Show("string") class from Mads Kristensen as below....

```
public static class Alert
{

    /// <summary> 
    /// Shows a client-side JavaScript alert in the browser. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="message">The message to appear in the alert.</param> 

    public static void Show(string message)
    {
        // Cleans the message to allow single quotation marks 
        string cleanMessage = message.Replace("'", "\\'");

       //replacing  script string with strSCript
        //string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('" + cleanMessage + "');</script>";

        //added this below
        string strScript = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\">";
        strScript += "alert('" + cleanMessage + "');";
        strScript += "window.location.href='http://localhost/Gadgeteer/IncToH/IncToH.zip';";
        strScript += "</script>";


        // Gets the executing web page 
        Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

        // Checks if the handler is a Page and that the script isn't allready on the Page 
        if (page != null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("alert"))
        {
            page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Alert), "alert", strScript);

        }
    }

}
//calling from code behind
Alert.Show("message");
```

Comment: Works for me.  The redirection occurs after the alert is displayed.

Comment: I don't see an issue with the code you've posted.  Try checking the source being sent down to the browser to identify a potential issue.  I took your javascript and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have something malformed in the alert function and that is failing, but the redirect is not.  Please review what is rendered to the browser and consider improving your alert message.  If the messages are dynamic, please be careful to avoid XSS.

Comment: I appreciate all the answers.Thank you very much Alison and Kenny.What is the best way to check the browser rendering, is there a tool that i can use to pause and check?Sorry for the basic question,but i'm not that knowledgeable.

Comment: A simple way is to right click on the page and select "View Source" or "View Page Source".  The exact menu option will differ between browsers.  Just look for the script block when it is failing and post it back in your question.  If you have a hard time getting it because of the redirect, you can try using a tool like firebug or fiddler.

Comment: Hi Kenny and Alison,Thanks again for the reply.I have wasted everyone's time.I had two redirections,one in the Alert class and another in the code behind page,which was not commented out.Embarrasing.Thanks again for the help,and the tips for using firebug.